# Designing an advanced permission system

Tags: mysql, permissions

I am currently wanting to implement a permission system, whereby it is convenient to add permissions as life goes on (by using rows instead of fields in MySQL). Each permission will have 5 bits: view, add, delete, modify, value. Ill give examples to explain this structure better. The thing is, with this system, I want to be able to give admins permissions to GIVE permissions as well as grant normal users permissions to do various tasks.

**Example 1:**

A forum

Approach 1)

There would be a permission called can_create_topic and can_modify_topic_name and can_delete_own_topic ETC ETC

Approach 2)

There would be a permission called topic and it would have subpermissions or bits: add, modify, view, delete. I like this approach better, just dont know how to implement this.

**Example 2:**

I also want to grant users permissions that are also other than yes or no permissions, for example max_number_of_topics_per_hour, which is an input value.

**Example 3:**

I want to grant other administrators (say i am super admin) permissions about giving permissions. For example, one administrator would be able to modify can_create_topic for UserA but not for UserB and so on. How do i go about doing all this?

Comment: SO is not appropriate for design discussions. You need to ask specific questions about code that you've written, in order to get help making it work.

Comment: i have found other questions similar to mine but not quiet the same

Comment: You could try this question at a cousin of SO, named [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @davejal This question would probably get closed as "too broad", since it's not so much asking about a problem with a design as it is listing a few requirements then asking us to do all the designing from scratch. Also, prefer flagging for moderator migration over commenting, because comments with links tend to result in cross-posting.

Comment: Yes, I flagged it as to broad, because couldn't flag to as off topic and belongs to another site on stack exchange.

Comment: One part of your problem will be designing the data structures to record what different users are allowed to do.  Another, probably bigger, part of your problem will be making the DBMS enforce activities according to the rules you want enforced.  Without enforcement mechanisms, the rules on who can do what are not very helpful (and enforcement mechanisms without data specifying who can do what are not very helpful either).  It all adds up to a very broad topic.

Comment: okay, implementing a CRUD system will work in most situations, say: forum -> topic -> create, forum -> topic -> delete. but what about forum -> topic -> max_creations_per_hour??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for writing here the solution which is not part of code.

I am using this solution for my projects

you need to create 6 tables

- userroles (id, name, status)
- users (id, name, email, password, user_role_id, status)
- permissionentities (id, entity_name, status)
- permissionrules (id, entity_name_id, rule_name, status)
- userrolespermissions (id, user_role_id, permission_rule_id, rule_value)
- userpermissions (id, user_id, permission_rule_id)

In this way,

- You can add entities like table names.
- You can add rules with respect to entities and you can add Create, Update, Delete, Read, PerHourRecords etc etc
- You can set rule value like per hour records for entity forum is 100. otherwise rule_value will be empty
- You can set permissions based on user roles like all admin have these rights, all editors have these rights
- Also, you can set permission for specific user that normally all editor have rights to submit 10 posts per hour for blog entity but User1 can submit 12.

Of course, you need to make interface for these settings

Comment: nice! dont u need a rule_value in userpermissions? and can u give me an example on a status?

Comment: rule_value is only for adding limit like recordsPerHour will be 10 or whatelse you want to ristrict. And about status, that is just for enable or disable like you created CRUD rules for FORUM entity. but after few days you think that DELETE should not be part of permissions (want to keep all records) then you can disable DELETE rule. So in Entity Forum, there will be CRU rules.

Comment: i know, but you wrote: userrolespermissions (id, user_role_id, permission_rule_id, RULE_VALUE) meaning that user roles (super admin, admin, member, guest) can have specific rules that are not yes/no like CRUD. but what about userpermissions? dont they need a field called rule_value?

Comment: Well, its up to you. 

you can add rule_value in userrolespermissions and also userpermissions.

if you want to give some specific value based on userRoles then you need rule_value in userrolespermissions. 
same with userpermissions.

Comment: whats the difference between permissionentities and permissionrules? can you give an example?

Comment: entities like the database tables (blog, forum, categories)
rules like (in blog entity, create, update, read, delete, recordperhour, canmodify) etc

Comment: okay i get it. very very nice. thanks!

Comment: can u give me an example for what the status for a userrole id would be? do you mean like: enabled, disabled?

Comment: Yes status means enable/disable (its up to you that you want to keep status in table) I do because any time, if we need to disable EDITOR user role i just go to admin panel and disable this role.

Comment: what about this: i want to sell more than one product. with your system, i can create a userrole called Pro, for ppl who paid. But what about ppl who paid for product A, but not product B? i can only put one user role per user in your system.

Comment: In that case, you need to add userpermissions (id, user_id, permission_rule_id, RULE_VALUE) here you can specificy user_id and PermissionEntity : Products, PermissionRuleId : ReadProductId, RuleValue : productB like this you can give access specific product to specific user.

Comment: hmm true. okay im getting a good idea on how to work things out thanks to you! thanks!

Comment: You welcome :) you can discuss with me generic level modules or advance things. I am working on these now a days.

Comment: how can i come in contact with you should i have further questions? i dont think we can write too much on this page

Comment: Visit my profile. :)

Comment: okay one last question. how do i access all of this through PHP? say i create an entity Topic, permission rule Create, Rule Value 1, and userid or userroleid of 1.

Comment: you need to keep userID and userRoleId in session at login time, the user role and based on that you can get query and allow access the page otherwise you can redirect to dashboard with message "You are not Allowed to access the requested page."

Comment: okay awesome! i get it. u have a very cool homepage!

Comment: but isnt it better to have the entity Product B instead of generally Products? then in Rule Value you can set it to either 1 or 0.

Comment: Well, as we have settled that entities will contains table names only, rules will be dependent on entities and for specification we will use rule_value. In this way, you can add any product, blog to any user. ... otherwise if you will add product B in entities, then you need to add PHP code that if its entity name is like "Product " then check in products table if its like "Article " then check in articles tables and so on.

Comment: i have thought about this and i came up with the idea of altering the entities table = (id, parent, child, bit). Example: Parent -> Forum, Child -> Topic, Bit -> Post. Say you want to check whether a forum (not topic or post) can be renamed by an admin. then you need to have an enitity Forum, but child and bit fields are empty. This way it can be easily organized in Admin CP when displaying different rules.

Comment: Yes you can do like that. Its up to you that how you modify and make your self comfortable.

Comment: awesome. thanks again for your support!

Comment: but if i want to do things your way (having Product as entity). say our entity is Forum. Is Topic another entity? and Post?

Comment: Forum have posts ? right ... in that case posts will be as entity. 
if you are saving posts/topics in FORUMs table then you can set FORUMs as entity.

Comment: no, forums dont have posts. but topics have posts. and we have posts inside topics.

Comment: then if you want to add permission on FORUM then add forum as entity
if you want to add permissions on topics then add topics as entity and so on

Comment: okay. but the hierarchy is Forum -> Topic -> Post. Would it be a good idea to have a field called parent_entity_id to help with organization? say Forum is entityid = 1, Topic is 2 and Post is 3. Topic's parent_entity_id would be 1, Posts parent_entity_id would be 2

Comment: Yes you can add if you want to manage with respect to parent :)

Comment: what if the permission is create, update, read or delete? what is the value of RULE_VALUE?